# How to launch a set of program inside tmux or gnome-terminal within a script?

Tags: command-line, terminal, concurrency

I wanted to launch a few commands simultaneously in tmux or gnome-terminal or xfterminal , 
every different tab with a single command running , and close that tab when that command finishes.

Any other software is welcomed as well

I wanted to issue a single script to do the job , e.g XX "cmd1" "cmd2" "cmd3"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
tmux new -d -s my-session 'echo window-1 pane-1; sleep 8' \; \
          split-window -d 'echo window-1 pane-2; sleep 6' \; down-pane \; \
            new-window -d 'echo window-2;        sleep 4' \; next-window \; \
                attach \;
```

The above is a running example of the general idea ... more here: [How to run streamripper and mplayer in a split-screen X terminal, via a single script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15924/how-to-run-streamripper-and-mplayer-in-a-split-screen-x-terminal-via-a-single-s)

Answer (score 49):

Open a tmux session and start the first command. Then launch more commands on new windows and evenly distribute the window sizes at the end.

```
tmux \
  new-session  "command1 ; read" \; \
  split-window "command2 ; read" \; \
  split-window "command3 ; read" \; \
  split-window "command4 ; read" \; \
  select-layout even-vertical
```

The `read` after each command causes the window to stay open after the command has finished so that you can read the output.

Comment: This answer deserves more votes. Thanks man.

Comment: How would you keep the windows opened after the commands are done?

Comment: @MasterScrat:
the `read` that danijar put after each command will keep the window open until you type a return.

**Alternatively**, you can replace the read by:
**a.** `cat > /dev/null` if you fear typing return by error (the cat will require a Ctrl-D);
**b.** `bash` (or your preferred shell) if you want to do some manual housekeeping after the command (ls -l to see if your command generated the expected output file, and so on)

Answer (score 8):

If it's always the same configuration of programs, you can use a tool like [teamocil](https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil).

You'll need to create with a configuration (e.g. `~/.teamocil/sample`), which contains something like:

```
windows:
  - name: my-first-window
    root: ~/Projects/foo-www
    filters:
      before: "rvm use 1.9.2"
      after: "echo 'I am done initializing this split.'"
    splits:
      - cmd: "git status"
      - cmd: "bundle exec rails server --port 4000"
        width: 50
      - cmd:
          - sudo service memcached start
          - sudo service mongodb start
        height: 50
```

And then you can run: `tmux new-session -d "teamocil sample" \; attach`

Answer (score 6):

With `gnome-terminal` it would be:

```
gnome-terminal --window -e 'cmd1' --tab -e 'cmd2' --tab -e 'cmd3'
```

Each tab will be closed after its command is finished.

Comment: great as well , but i do prefer tmux this time ;-P