# How to run multiple programs in one single terminal window?

Tags: tmux, command, gnome-terminal

I would like to write a script that runs multiple programs/commands *'program1'*, *'program2'*, *'program3'*... in a mosaic of terminal in one single window using `gnome-terminal` and also using `tmux` (I mean I want to know both ways).

How is it possible ?

I know that this [topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22682/171538) mentions it, but it's not exactly what I want. Since I don't want the terminal to close when the program has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Put everything in a script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
su -c '/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s "all" -d'
tmux send "path of Program 1" C-m
tmux rename-window "Program 1"

tmux new-window
tmux send "path of Program 2" C-m
tmux rename-window "Program 2"

tmux new-window
tmux send "path of Program 3" C-m
tmux rename-window "Program 3"

tmux attach
```

It will start a new tmux session called **all** with 3 windows called *Program1*,*Program2* and *Program3* each one executing each program.

Even if a program stops the window won't close.

Comment: I have tried what you say but no window appears. I replace `"path of Program 1"` with `"$AtmosBrokerPath/AtmosBroker -v"` in my case. ($AtmosBrokerPath is a path that I initialize in the script)

Comment: Did you mean `send-keys`, not just `send`?

Comment: Soory. My bad. It lacked the command `tmux attach`at the end. I corrected it.

Comment: Do you need to run these commands as root ?

Comment: @bam500 Not necessarily. As log as the user can run `tmux`and the `Programs` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the terminal open by following the command with something that waits for user input:

```
tmux new-window 'make ; read'
```

If your shell doesn't support the `read` builtin, you could use eg. `sed -n q`.